# Let X and Y be a random variables with $E(X) = 5$, $Var(X) = 30$, $E(Y ) = -5$, $Var(Y ) = 10$ and $Cov(X, Y ) = 7$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

(a) Find $E(2X-3Y+1)$.

(b) Find $E((X-2Y)^2)$.

(c) Find $Var(3X-Y+pi)$

First I found $E(X^2)$ and $E(Y^2)$ using the given values

for (a) I have $2E(X)-3E(Y)+1$

for (b) I come up with: $E(X^2)-4E(X)E(Y)+4E(Y^2)$ I think this is incorrect because I have COV(X,Y) meaning the X and Y are not independent, any ideas about (b)?

for (c) I came up with: $V(3X-Y+pi) = V(3X)-V(Y) = (3)^2V(X)-V(Y)$ which I'm also not convinced is correct, any ideas on (c)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b), we want $E(X^2-4XY+4Y^2)$, which is $E(X^2)-4E(XY)+4E(Y^2)$.

However, we cannot say in general that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. To calculate $E(XY)$, recall perhaps that $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. We know the covariance, and $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$, so we know $E(XY)$.

For (c), as you know the $\pi$ makes no difference. We use the formula 
$$\text{Var}(U+V)=\text{Var}(U)+\text{Var}(V)+2\text{Cov}(U,V).$$ 
In our case we end up with $9\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-6\text{Cov}(X,Y)$.